# You try to generate GraphQL Type with name "Projects" from mongoose model but this type already exists in SchemaComposer

Tags: graphql-compose, graphql-compose-mongoose

I use different mongodb db's to store the same mongoose schema records "Pages". Because of that i wanted to have X graphql endpoints - each should serve the "Pages" of the requested database.

Example: `localhost:3000/graphql/:database`

For that reason i created a schemaComposer that gets the database name from a route (express > request.param.database)

```
import { composeMongoose } from 'graphql-compose-mongoose'
import { SchemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose'
import { Pages } from '../../mongoose/models/PagesModel.js'
import { Projects } from '../../mongoose/models/ProjectsModel.js'

const gqlSchemaComposerBuilder = (database) => {
    const gqlSchemaComposer = new SchemaComposer()

    const ProjectsTC = composeMongoose(Projects, {})
    const PagesTC = composeMongoose(Pages(database), {})

    gqlSchemaComposer.Query.addFields({
        pageMany: PagesTC.mongooseResolvers.findMany(),
        pageOne: PagesTC.mongooseResolvers.findOne(),

        projectMany: ProjectsTC.mongooseResolvers.findMany(),
        projectOne: ProjectsTC.mongooseResolvers.findOne()
    })

    gqlSchemaComposer.Mutation.addFields({
        projectCreateOne: ProjectsTC.mongooseResolvers.createOne(),
        projectUpdateOne: ProjectsTC.mongooseResolvers.updateOne(),
        projectRemoveOne: ProjectsTC.mongooseResolvers.removeOne()
    })

    return gqlSchemaComposer.buildSchema()
}

export default gqlSchemaComposerBuilder
```

The Problem is, as soon as the both `composeMongoose` declarations are wrapped inside the function i get this Error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"You try to generate GraphQL Type with name Projects from mongoose model but this type already exists in SchemaComposer. Please choose another type name \"composeWithMongoose(model, { name: 'NewTypeName' })\", or reuse existed type \"schemaComposer.getOTC('TypeName')\", or remove type from SchemaComposer before calling composeWithMongoose method \"schemaComposer.delete('TypeName')\"."}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default `composeMongoose()` uses the global `schemaComposer`, so you need to pass your `gqlSchemaComposer` in the options of `componseMongo`

```
const gqlSchemaComposer = new SchemaComposer()

const ProjectsTC = composeMongoose(Projects, { schemaComposer: gqlSchemaComposer })
const PagesTC = composeMongoose(Pages(database), {schemaComposer: gqlSchemaComposer})
```